# How to get attr_accessor really working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, attr-accessor

Here are the code snippets which are working for me

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def full_name
    [first_name,last_name].join(" ")
  end

  def full_name=(name)
    split = name.split(" ",2)
    self.first_name = split.first
    self.last_name = split.last
  end
end
```

Then here are the views files

**Show File**

```
<h1>
    <%= @user.full_name %>
</h1>
```

**Edit File**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :full_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :full_name %>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

I have read **attr_accessor** works same as

```
  def full_name
    [first_name,last_name].join(" ")
  end

  def full_name=(name)
    split = name.split(" ",2)
    self.first_name = split.first
    self.last_name = split.last
  end
```

So I tried like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :full_name
end
```

I am not able to figure out what else should be done.

Neither is shows complete name in show page nor update the same in the database when form gets submitted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not correct. `attr_accessor` works like

```
def full_name
  @full_name
end

def full_name=(value)
  @full_name = value
end
```

It just creates primitive getter / setter for your instance variable. If you need any kind of advanced processing (split / join in your case), you need to define getter and setter method yourself.

Comment: I was thinking if it was possible using attr_accessor.

Comment: This does not explain a solution to the problem experienced i.e. the question.